# Collapsing a (General) Simple Quadrupole to line? What are the separations needed to preserve the quadrupole moment?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

I was told that simple quadrupoles could be collapsed to a line and I am trying to figure out the dimensions(separations of charges along the line) that would overall preserve the quadrupole moment. Unfortunately I'm running into problems.

First figure below shows a simple quadrupole, the second figure shows its supposed collapse that preserves the quadrupole moment.

I used the formula

$Q_{ij} = \sum_a q_a[3x_ix_j - x^2 \delta_{ij}]$

In the **first instance** I am getting

$(-q)$ at $l_i$

$(+q)$ at $l_i + a_i$

$(+q)$ at $l_i + b_i$

$(-q)$ at $l_i + a_i + b_i$

$Q_{ij} = -6qa_{i}b_{j}$

In the **second instance** I am getting the following coordinates (I projected $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ onto $\vec{l}$ and added it to $\vec{l}$)

**I assumed $\vec{l}$ was parallel to the diagonal of the quadrupole**

$(-q)$ at $l_i$

$(+q)$ at $\frac{b_il_il_i}{l^2} + l_i$

$(+q)$ at $\frac{b_il_il_i}{l^2} + l_i$

$(-q)$ at $l_i + a_i + b_i$

I am getting

$Q_{ij} = - 6qa_ib_j + 2qab \delta_{ij}$

So pretty much the same thing except for the addition of a pesky cross term. Assuming I set up the vector components correctly in the second instance I don't see how we can avoid the cross term.

Could anyone steer me in the right direction? I feel like I am very close. It's just that pesky cross term!

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Supposed Quadrupole Collapse]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ljhD.png)